# Google App Script timestamp and set active user email as note in dynamic column on row edit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I'd like to dynamically set the value of a cell in column "date updated" and add a note in the same cell whenever a change to that row is made (on edit)

The cell value should be timestamp and the active user email should go in the note.

The Column position changes frequently so it can't be based on the column letter. Perhaps a named range is the way to go?

This is close to what I want to work:

```
function onEdit(e){
  // Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
  var range = e.range; 
  var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  range.setNote(userEmail + 'Last modified: ' + new Date());  

}
```

However this places the active user email AND timestamp on the edited cell.  I'd like to place the timestamp in the cell within the column "date updated" and the active user email to the note whenever any cells in that particular row are updated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add timestamp to named column in Google Spreadsheet onEdit script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462918/add-timestamp-to-named-column-in-google-spreadsheet-onedit-script)

Comment: Can you share your data with us and also explain how and why the columns are changing.

Comment: Actually @Rubén was correct - that linked google sheet was enough to solve my problem :) Thanks mate.